# Primes as sum of squares in finite field

Tags: finite-fields, sums-of-squares

Is there an algorithm to find integers such that the following holds true :
${a_1}^2 + {a_2}^2 \dots + {a_k}^2 \equiv p $ $(mod $ $n)$, where $p$ is a prime and $n$ is any general integer.

By [Lagrange 4 square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_four-square_theorem) it is known that value of $k$ will be atmost 4. Also according to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1266433/squares-in-a-finite-field) since, we are working in modular fields, the value of $k$ will be atmost 2, i.e. when it is not a quadratic residue. But I was interested in finding the integers rather than value of $k$. Please suggest an efficient algorithm for the above.

Comment: What do you mean "the maximum value"?  Perhaps you meant "at most"? Since if it is true for $\;n=4\;$ then it is true for any $\;m>n\;$ , of course.

Comment: Updated the statement.

Comment: can someone please explain how the sum of squares in "modular fields" differ from the regular sum of squares a^2 + b^2  +... c^2 = n?.

Comment: For example, in modular field $4^2 + 1^2 \equiv 3 $ $(mod$ $ 7)$, which is not the case in normal integer system.